# implementation of Conway's game of life in C for ansi terminals

Tags: c, game-of-life

I've been learning C for some quite time now and wanted to test my skills by implementing the game of life in C. Please give me a general review, and include the style. Is code like that of function fetch_pop good or should I be more clear? Should I put more comments? If so, can you give me some examples? Can I improve the algorithm in any way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define clear_screen printf("\033[2J\033[H")

#define WIDTH 20
#define LENGTH 50
                                                                                                                                                                    
enum cell { dead, alive };

int world[WIDTH][LENGTH];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  isnum(char *p);
    void initialize(int width, int length, int level),
         draw(int width, int length),
         evolve(int width, int length);
    
    int level = 10;
    
    while (--argc > 0) {
        if (isnum(*(++argv))) {
            level = atoi(*argv);
            break;
        }
    }
        
    initialize(WIDTH, LENGTH, level);
    do
    {
        clear_screen;
        draw(WIDTH, LENGTH);
        evolve(WIDTH, LENGTH);
    } while (getchar() == '\n');
    
    return 0;
}

int isnum(char *p)
{
    while (*p != '\0')
        if (!isdigit(*p++))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

void initialize(int width, int length, int level)
{
    int col, ln;

    for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++)
        for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
            world[ln][col] = rand() < RAND_MAX / level;
}

void draw(int width, int length)
{
    int col, ln;

    for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++) {
        for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
            printf("%c", world[ln][col] ? '@' : ' ');
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void evolve(int width, int length)
{
    int fetch_pop(int ln, int col, int width, int length); /* fetch population number of cell ln, col's neighbors exclusive */
    int temp[width][length];
    int ln, col, pop;

    for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++) {
        for (col = 0; col < length; col++) {
            if ((pop = fetch_pop(ln, col, width, length)) == 3)
                temp[ln][col] = alive;
            else if (pop == 2)
                temp[ln][col] = world[ln][col];
            else
                temp[ln][col] = dead;
        }
    }
    
    for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++)
        for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
            world[ln][col] = temp[ln][col];
}

int fetch_pop(int ln, int col, int width, int length)
{
    int pop;
    int lns, lne, cols, cole;

    lns = ln - (ln > 0); 
    lne = ln + (ln < width-1);
    cols = col - (col > 0);
    cole = col + (col < length-1);
    pop = 0;

    for (int i = lns; i <= lne; i++)
        for (int j = cols; j <= cole; j++)
            pop += world[i][j];
    
    return pop - world[ln][col];
}
```

Comment: The {draw, evolve} loop is lovely. Dunno how much flicker you're seeing from CLS. Consider sending just "go to upper-left home", ESC [ H, within the loop, so that `draw()` keeps overwriting what it displayed in the previous generation. // Rather than (width, length) it would be more usual to name them (height, width). // Consider saving some `write(2)` system calls by using `putc('\n');` instead of printf newline, and then manually `fflush` stdout before returning.

Comment: Always use `{}`s around blocks.

Comment: @J_H Why didn't you provide an answer?

Comment: @pacmaninbw, I used to write C, but abandoned it due to frustrations with Undefined Behavior, and the language has moved on in recent years. I prefer to see a C expert do the "real" review. I was just making some language-agnostic "hit the soft. eng. highlights" observations. Besides, occasionally someone will post a Question, read my comment, and make edits prior to an Answer being posted. I feel that when a higher quality submission is reviewed, that is always a win.

Comment: I would make `clear_screen` a regular function instead of a macro: `static void clear_screen(void) { printf("\033[2J\033[H"); }`

Comment: @J_H "using putc('\n'); instead of printf newline" --> Perhaps.  Good compilers already make this optimization and emit efficient code either way.  I'd go for clarity here - which is subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`isnum()` improvements**

- `isdigit(*p++)` risks *undefined behavior* (UB) when `*p < 0`.  This is possible when `char` is *signed*.  In general, standard library *string* functions operate on the characters as if they were `unsigned char`, even when `char` is *signed*.
- Rather than 2 checks per iteration, use one by taking advantage that `isdigit('\0') == 0`.
- Use pointers to `const` data when possible - potentially faster and has wider application.
- Pedantic: I'd expect `isnum("")` to return 0, so check that at least 1 digit found.

```
#include <ctype.h>

int isnum(const char *p) {
  const unsigned char *u = (const unsigned char*) p;
  while (isdigit(*u)) {
    u++;
  }
  return *p == '\0' && u > (const unsigned char*) p;
}
```

---

**Do not allow bad program arguments**

Instead of allowing multiple arguments and ignoring non-numeric ones, be pickier.

```
int level = 10;

//while (--argc > 0) {
//    if (isnum(*(++argv))) {
//        level = atoi(*argv);
//        break;
//    }
//}

if (argc == 2 && isnum(argv[1])) {
  level = atoi(argv[1]);
} else if (argc > 1) {
  ; // TBD error message
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Consider `strtol()` rather than `isnum()` and `atof()`.

Consider a range check on `level`.

---

**Reduce memory**

`int world[][]` only ever use 2 values: 0 & 1.  Consider `signed char[][]` instead.  Makes little difference in OP's code, but when the array dimensions are 100000s, 1000000s, sure to improve throughput.

Likewise for `temp[][]`

---

**Use `memcpy()` when one can**

Copying the array deserves performance considerations.

```
for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++)
  // for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
  //  world[ln][col] = temp[ln][col];
  memcpy(world[ln], temp[ln], sizeof temp[ln]);
```

---

**I/O**

Rather than print 1 `char` at a time, consider printing a *line* at a time to reduce the heavy I/O overhead.

---

**Minor: maybe clearer code**

- `"\033[2J\033[H"` can be unclear.  Perhaps a comment with a URL table of escape sequences?
- Avoid `printf(s)` as a later version of `s` may include a `'%'`.

An alternative:

```
//#define clear_screen printf("\033[2J\033[H")

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Description
#define ESC "\033"
#define ANSI_CLEAR_ENTIRE_SCREEN ESC "[2J"
#define ANSI_CURSOR_POSITION_UPPER_LEFT ESC "[H"
#define clear_screen fputs(ANSI_CLEAR_ENTIRE_SCREEN ANSI_CURSOR_POSITION_UPPER_LEFT, stdout)
```

Better as a function [@G. Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287086/implementation-of-conways-game-of-life-in-c-for-ansi-terminals/287132#comment571660_287086).

---

**Off-by-1 ?**

`world[ln][col] = rand() < RAND_MAX / level;` looks amiss.

What does one really mean by *level*?

At least a comment is deserved in code.

---

**Common function names**

Use less likely to collide function names.  Then easier to import this code as part of a larger code set.

```
// draw()
// evolve()
gol_draw()  // gol --> game of life
gol_evolve()
```

Answer (score 4):

## General Observations

Function Prototypes should be declared before all the functions in the file. In a single file program like this it is better to put the main() function at the bottom of the file and all the functions that get used in the proper order above main(). Keep in mind that every line of code written is another line of code where a bug can crawl into the code.

Based on the implementation you will always start with the same screen, since you are not seeding the pseudo random number generator. If you want to see different screens every time you need to add a call to `srand()` in main before the call to `initialize()`.

A suggestion is to create a type using typedef for all instances of world to use. The `temp` variable in the `evolve()` function should use this type.

```
    typedef int WORLD[WIDTH][LENGTH];

    WORLD world;
```

```
    void evolve(int width, int length)
    {
        WORLD temp;
```

> Should I put more comments?
> You only need to comment for design decisions. The code should self document through good use of variable names and function names as much as possible. Comments need to be maintained if the code changes.

Most of the functions don't need the `width` and `length` arguments, they can just use the `WIDTH` and `LENGTH` constant macros instead.

## Prefer Braces `{` and `}` Around Single Statements in `if` or `loops`

This was mentioned in a comment by ggorlen.

Some programmers consider this a style issue, but it makes it much easier to read and maintain the code if each in an `if`, `else` or `loop` block is embedded within braces. Extending the functionality of these statements can be problematic when the braces are not used. For a more in depth discussion of this see the first 2 answers on this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797286/are-braces-necessary-in-one-line-statements-in-javascript). As one of the answers points out this is true in all C like languages (C, C++, C#, JavaScript, Java, etc.). I have worked at multiple companies where this was required in the coding standard and flagged during code reviews.

```
    {
        int col, ln;

        for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++)
        {
            for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
            {
                world[ln][col] = rand() < RAND_MAX / level;
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(int width, int length)
    {
        int col, ln;

        for (ln = 0; ln < width; ln++) {
            for (col = 0; col < length; col++)
            {
                printf("%c", world[ln][col] ? '@' : ' ');
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

## Declare the Variables as Needed

A recommended programming practice to declare the variable as needed. The C language doesn't provide a default initialization of the variable so variables should be initialized as part of the declaration. For readability and maintainability each variable should be declared and initialized on its own line. The scope of the variables should be limited to just where they are needed.

```
    void evolve(int width, int length)
    {
        WORLD temp = { 0 };

        for (int ln = 0; ln < width; ln++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < length; col++) {
                int pop = fetch_pop(ln, col, width, length);
                if (pop == 3)
                    temp[ln][col] = alive;
                else if (pop == 2)
                    temp[ln][col] = world[ln][col];
                else
                    temp[ln][col] = dead;
            }
        }

        for (int ln = 0; ln < width; ln++)
            for (int col = 0; col < length; col++)
                world[ln][col] = temp[ln][col];
    }
```